# Insertar valores por defecto MySql despues de 1 minuto

Tags: mysql

Necesito saber como insertar automáticamente una fila con valores por defecto con una condición de tiempo (el script debe evaluar si no hay una inserción de dato desde 1 minuto y luego insertar la fila por defecto), ¿como puedo automatizar el script para que evalúe primero el tiempo de ultima inserción?

Mi tabla:

```
id  int(11) PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
codigo_maquina  tinyint(2)  
corriente   smallint(5) 
velocidad   smallint(5) 
codigo_estado   smallint(5) 
estado  char(20)    
fecha_hora  timestamp   YES     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

La query que quiero dejar como defecto sería así:

```
  INSERT INTO maquina(codigo_maquina, corriente, velocidad, 
  codigo_estado, estado) VALUES (1, 0, 0, 5, 'Fuera de Linea');
```

Gracias de antemano!